# Error when adding custom view to subgrid "Add existing button"

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to add a custom view to the popup when a user goes to add existing records in a subgrid for a many to many relationship.

I followed the instructions on the following [link](http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/magnetismsolutionscrmblog/archive/2013/02/04/filter-n-n-add-existing-lookup-dynamics-crm-2011-rollup-12.aspx#.UT8xpKWePzg)

But when I go to add existing records it throws a generic error, one that doesn't allow me to download the log file. Can anyone point me in the right direction to find out why this isn't working?

I'll post the code below.

```js
function FilterSubGridLookup(gridTypeCode, gridControl, primaryEntity) {

if (primaryEntity != "ts_pmo_activity_request") {

    Mscrm.GridRibbonActions.addExistingFromSubGridAssociated(gridTypeCode, gridControl);
}
else {

    var fetchXml = '<fetch distinct="false" mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0"> -<entity name="ts_qualification_area"> <attribute name="ts_qualification_areaid"/> <attribute name="ts_descriptor"/> <attribute name="createdon"/> <order descending="false" attribute="ts_descriptor"/> -<filter type="and"> <condition attribute="ts_solution_qualification_id" value="' + solutionQualificationId + '" uitype="ts_solution_qualification" operator="eq"/> </filter> </entity> </fetch>';
    var layoutXml = "<grid name='resultset' object='1' jump='ts_qualification_areaid' select='1' icon='1' preview='1'><row name='result' id='ts_qualification_areaid'><cell name='ts_descriptor' width='150' /></row></grid>";

    addExistingFromSubGridCustom(gridTypeCode, gridControl, fetchXml, layoutXml, "Filtered Qualification Areas");
}    
}
```

```js
function addExistingFromSubGridCustom(gridTypeCode, gridControl, fetch, layout, viewName) {

var viewId = "{1DFB2B35-B07C-44D1-868D-258DEEAB88E2}"; // a dummy view ID 

var relName, roleOrd;

if (typeof (gridControl.GetParameter) === "function") { //post rollup 12 
    relName = gridControl.GetParameter("relName");
    roleOrd = gridControl.GetParameter("roleOrd");
}
else { //pre rollup 12 
    relName = gridControl.getParameter("relName");
    roleOrd = gridControl.getParameter("roleOrd");
}

//creates the custom view object 
var customView = {
    fetchXml: fetch,
    id: viewId,
    layoutXml: layout,
    name: viewName,
    recordType: gridTypeCode,
    Type: 0
};

//pops the lookup window with our view injected 
var lookupItems = LookupObjects(null, "multi", gridTypeCode, 0, null, "", null, null, null, null, null, null, viewId, [customView]);

//once the lookup window is closed, we need the parent record ID and ETC before associating selected records 
if (lookupItems && lookupItems.items.length > 0) {
    var parentId;
    var parentTypeCode;
    if (typeof (GetParentObject) == "function") { //post rollup 12 has its own function to get this 
        var parent = GetParentObject();
        parentId = parent.id;
        parentTypeCode = parent.objectTypeCode;
    }
    else { //pre rollup 12 still needs to use the old way 
        var parent = typeof (crmFormSubmit) == "undefined" ? $get("crmFormSubmit") : crmFormSubmit; //according to daniels blog crmFormSubmit should already be defined, but it's not... 
        if (parent) {
            parentId = parent.crmFormSubmitId.value;
            parentTypeCode = parent.crmFormSubmitObjectType.value;
        }
        else {
            parentId = window.parent.crmFormSubmit.crmFormSubmitId.value;
            parentTypeCode = window.parent.crmFormSubmit.crmFormSubmitObjectType.value;
        }
    }

    //associates the selected records 
    AssociateObjects(parentTypeCode, parentId, gridTypeCode, lookupItems, IsNull(roleOrd) || roleOrd == 2, "", relName);
}   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your fetch xml you have dashes.  See if removing them fixes your problem:

Before:

```
<fetch distinct="false" mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0"> 
-<entity name="ts_qualification_area">
    <attribute name="ts_qualification_areaid"/>
    <attribute name="ts_descriptor"/>
    <attribute name="createdon"/>
    <order descending="false" attribute="ts_descriptor"/> 
    -<filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="ts_solution_qualification_id" value="' + solutionQualificationId + '" uitype="ts_solution_qualification" operator="eq"/>
    </filter>
</entity>
```

After:

```
<fetch distinct="false" mapping="logical" output-format="xml-platform" version="1.0"> 
    <entity name="ts_qualification_area">
        <attribute name="ts_qualification_areaid"/>
        <attribute name="ts_descriptor"/>
        <attribute name="createdon"/>
        <order descending="false" attribute="ts_descriptor"/> 
        <filter type="and">
            <condition attribute="ts_solution_qualification_id" value="' + solutionQualificationId + '" uitype="ts_solution_qualification" operator="eq"/>
        </filter>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: Have made the change and its still throwing an error. It loads up the window to select the items, and appears like it will work but then the error pops up. If I close the error window though it has changed to my custom view but where the records would be it just shows the loading message. Wrapping the bit where it fails (where it sets the lookup items) in a try catch block doesn't pick up the error either

Comment: @jimminybob you can try to turn on trace logging.  Use the CRM diagnostic tool to turn on trace logging: http://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com (this is for on Premise only).

Comment: I found the error, it turns out that the value I was passing to my fetchXml wasn't valid, so it couldn't find the record I was trying to match against. Thanks for your help